# How dynamic cell height increase using card view in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

How to resolve the cell height and based on the text dynamic text

[image]

My code:

```
class NotificationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var notification:Notifications? {
didSet {
guard let notificationList = notification else {return}
if let title = notificationList.title{
titleLabel.text = title
}
if let message = notificationList.Message {
descriptionLabel.text = " \(message) "
}
}
}    
let ContentView = UIViewFactory()
.build()

//MARK: - cell title Label
let titleLabel = CustomLabel(text: "")
.changeNumberOfLines(lines: 1)
.buildUI()
//MARK: - cell description Label
let descriptionLabel = CustomLabel(text: "")
.changeTextAlignment(.left)
.changeLineBreakMode(mode: .byWordWrapping)
.changeFont(12)
.buildUI()
//MARK: - Time Label
let timeLabel = CustomLabel(text: "")
.buildUI()
//MARK: - IDPal Logo
let logo : UIImageView = {
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "idpal")
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return imageView
}()
override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()
// Initialization code
}
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
logo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
selectionStyle = .none
setUp()
}
//MARK: - SetUpViews
func setUp() {
addSubview(logo)
addSubview(titleLabel)
addSubview(descriptionLabel)
setUpConstraints()
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
super.layoutSubviews()

let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
contentView.clipsToBounds = true
contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.74, green: 0.74, blue: 0.74, alpha: 0.50).cgColor
contentView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1)
contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
contentView.alpha = 1 
contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))

//set the values for top,left,bottom,right margins
// let margins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
// contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: margins)
}

func setUpConstraints() {


// containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:topAnchor).isActive = true
// containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:leftAnchor).isActive = true
// containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:rightAnchor).isActive = true
// containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:bottomAnchor).isActive = true

//MARK: - IDPal Logo constraints
logo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:topAnchor,constant:10).isActive = true
logo.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:leftAnchor,constant:14).isActive = true
logo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:30).isActive = true
logo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:40).isActive = true
//MARK: - titleLabel constraints
titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:logo.topAnchor,constant:0).isActive = true
titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:logo.rightAnchor,constant:10).isActive = true
titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:rightAnchor).isActive = true
//MARK: - descriptionLabel constraints
descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
descriptionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant:10).isActive = true
descriptionLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
// Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Hear my code can't able to configure if found any suggestion drop here please.

adding the border with it's to be space between contendview but not working for me.
I would like to give shadow effect like card similar to the image in my iOS app
thanks

Comment: please add your code

Comment: refer this tutorial  https://www.sitepoint.com/self-sizing-cells-uitableview-auto-layout/

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: Code of the seems ok, but what about the code of UITableView?